# Convert bash script into HP-UX os compatible

Tags: bash, shell, hp-ux

```
{ lineno1=`grep 'CustCare_CR*' /Abhi_data/Copy_test_demo/T2.txt`
echo $lineno1
var1=`sed -e 's#.*Backuped_CustCare/\(\)#\1#' <<< "$lineno1"`
echo $var1
path1="/CATALINA_HOME/Backuped_CustCare/$var1"
#echo $path1
cd $path1
pwd

}
```

When I run this code on Solaris it works, but when I run on HP-UX the `<<<` this operator does not work. Do you know any alternative to `<<<`?

Comment: when i run this code on solaris then it works but when i run on shell then '<<<' this operator does not work..
Do you know any alternate to <<< this operator

Comment: shell means hp unix

Comment: `hpunix` is not a shell. Also, please specify which shell you have used on Solaris. In general, when writing shell scripts which are supposed to run on different platforms, you need first decide which shell you are going to use, and which version of the shell, because programming features typically vary between versions. The usual recommendation (if portability is important) is to use a POSIX shell, but with old versions of Solaris and/or HP-UX, not even the existence of this shell can be taken for granted.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `<<<` is supposed to denote a *here*-string, one possibility would be to pipe the word into the `sed` command:

```
 var1=`echo "$lineno1" | sed -e 's#.*Backuped_CustCare/\(\)#\1#'`
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the printf utility, instead, along with using `$()` instead of `` ` ``:

```
var1=$(printf "%s" "$lineno1" | sed -e 's#.*Backuped_CustCare/\(\)#\1#')
```

References:

- [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/117549)
- [What's the difference between $(stuff) and `stuff`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/5778/117549)